# Write a thrift server in scala using scrooge without Finagle

Tags: thrift, finagle

I knew the same question asked here
[Write a thrift server in scala using scrooge and client in python or ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549490/write-a-thrift-server-in-scala-using-scrooge-and-)
client-in-python-or-ruby, but no answer for "how to start a service without using finagle".